# Notepad++ type FTP plugin for sublime text, netbeans or eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans-7, sublimetext

I love sublime text. The only thing I dont like is that there is no built in FTP plugin. The sublime sftp package, http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp sucks when you are editing and uploading files continuously. I am looking for something like the notepad ftp, in which you can see all your files and folders on the side of your screen, when u edit something and click Ctrl+S, it uploads automatically to the server.
The alternate option is to use NetBeans or Eclipse for this. The main thing is that I should be able to see all the files and folders on the side and should be able to upload the changes just by saving. I tried the netbeans built in plugin but didnt satisfy me, or I was not doing it properly. please advise

Comment: The other problem is that you have to download all the files from your FTP server before you can read/edit them, which in NP++ you only need to download what you want to read.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync free and realy good alternative.

Comment: +1 FTPSync rocks! Also as a note: You should get Package Control (free) for sublime text 2.  It has tons of useful addons, including FTPSync.

Comment: Bad news - it doesn't support SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on a file in the sidebar (with SFTP) and select "SFTP/FTP -> Sync Local -> Remote" and it will automatically upload that file or directory when anything in it changes (such as when saving).

You can also select "SFTP/FTP -> Browse Remote" to browse and open files on the server directly. If you save files opened this way, they will be uploaded automatically as well.